# Is this an acceptable wordpress loop?

Tags: php, wordpress

New to php and the loop process. Is it okay to have html markups inside the loop? Also I often see something like `<?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>` or a more complicated version in other themes. Should I house the loop in a separate php file and call it in my posts page?

I just want to make sure that my loop follows the "wordpress rules" and does not look out of the norm. Here is my current loop code that does function properly:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?> 

    <h2 id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title(); ?>">
    <?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>

    <p>
        Published on <?php the_time('M j, Y'); ?> <br>
    </p>

    <p><em>
        by <?php the_author(', '); ?> in <?php the_category(', '); ?> | <?php comments_number(); ?><br>
    </em></p>

    <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($page->ID, 'home-thumb'); ?>

    <br>

    <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>
    <hr>

<?php endwhile; ?>

    <div class="navigation">
        <div class="alignleft"><?php previous_posts_link('&laquo; Previous Entries') ?></div>
        <div class="alignright"><?php next_posts_link('Next Entries &raquo;','') ?></div>
    </div>

<?php else: ?>
    <p><?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Looks good to me. You can have HTML markup within PHP. :)

Comment: It looks fine to me :) Is there a specific issue you're facing with it you want someone to help with?

Comment: @BeatAlex but remember the HTML has to be outside of the `<?php ?>` tags or otherwise it will cause a parse error :p

Comment: @WilliamPatton sorry yeah ha that's what I meant! I can see why that's unclear sorry!

Comment: @BeatAlex yeah I figured that's what you meant but it never does any harm to point it out for others that aren't as familiar with php :)

Answer (score 0):

It is ok to use markups in the loop, in fact most themes are done that way.

Functions like are just used for reusable code.
    get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );

If you are going to use that loop elsewhere, separate it into another file. If not, keep it in the same file.